# Drop all rows in a group if none of the rows match a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Im using a groupby on a name variable, I want to drop a subset of rows based on a string variable

How do I drop subset of rows if there is not a particular string present in that group?

```
        user-id                         time              event
0   AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh    28/06/2016 11:18    CONVERSION
1   AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh    28/06/2016 10:40    Organic Search
2   AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh    26/06/2016 10:06    Organic Search
3   AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh    07/05/2016 19:27    Display
4   AMsySZa-05iZ7gKLfZQ3_kw8l-mO    16/06/2016 09:05    CONVERSION
5   AMsySZa-05iZ7gKLfZQ3_kw8l-mO    21/06/2016 09:10    CONVERSION
6   AMsySZa-15QiL8a5kcw9LvAtBLiE    29/06/2016 20:35    Display
7   AMsySZa-15QiL8a5kcw9LvAtBLiE    27/05/2016 06:46    Display
8   AMsySZa-15QiL8a5kcw9LvAtBLiE    15/05/2016 00:17    Display
9   AMsySZa-15QiL8a5kcw9LvAtBLiE    15/05/2016 00:17    Display
```

I want to eliminate any subsets that dont have the word "conversion". My expected output would be:

```
                        user-id              time           event
0  AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh  28/06/2016 11:18      CONVERSION
1  AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh  28/06/2016 10:40  Organic Search
2  AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh  26/06/2016 10:06  Organic Search
3  AMsySZa--NczTTJGpJvNQTNri4nh  07/05/2016 19:27         Display
4  AMsySZa-05iZ7gKLfZQ3_kw8l-mO  16/06/2016 09:05      CONVERSION
5  AMsySZa-05iZ7gKLfZQ3_kw8l-mO  21/06/2016 09:10      CONVERSION
```

Comment: Yes I do! but I promise theres subsets without the word conversion

Comment: Are you grouping based on user-id? If yes, check the row for index 6.

Comment: PLEASE-DO-NOT-VANDALIZE-YOUR-POSTS. That was the second time you'd done so. You have been warned.

Comment: *row 1* to *row 3* in your expected output don't contain `conversion`. Why don't they get removed?