# Python - Keep all rows of a group if a name is contained in any row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a report that contains Invoice IDs and approvers. Invoices can have multiple approvers, which results in the IDs being duplicated (this is fine). What I want to do, is check each group of Invoice IDs to see if either of 2 approvers are in the list of approvers associated with that ID. If they are, then I want to keep *all* of the rows of that ID. I think my question is similar to this one: [Drop all rows in a group if none of the rows match a specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132761/drop-all-rows-in-a-group-if-none-of-the-rows-match-a-specific-condition) however no one has answered that one yet. Below is an example of what I'm going for.

```
**Invoice Id**    **Approver**
149877RV    Jane Doe
149877RV    Joe Manchin
149877RV    Michael Frank
149877RV    Kevin Holder
149877RV    Michael Frank
149877RV    Michael Frank
149877RV    James Doe
```

Michael Frank and Kevin Holder are the names I'm looking for. Since they are both present here (in my scenario it can be either one of them) I want to keep all of these rows.

```
150210  Jim Halpert   
150210  Mike Smith
150210  FP&A 
150210  Michael Scott
```

Since neither Michael Frank nor Kevin Holder are on this list, I want to remove all of these rows.

I haven't been able to find a solution that allows me to keep all rows as I'm describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'invoice_ID': ['149877RV' ,'149877RV' ,'149877RV','149877RV','149877RV','149877RV','149877RV'], 
                   'Approver': ['Jane Doe','Joe Manchin','Michael Frank','Kevin Holder','Michael Frank','Michael Frank','James Doe']})

mask=df['Approver'].isin(['Michael Frank','Kevin Holder'])
df1=df.loc[mask]
df1=df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['invoice_ID'])
mask2=df['invoice_ID'].isin(df1['invoice_ID'])

final_list=df.loc[mask2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your condition for each available invoice id.
Then check your condition and return the results. I merged your data in order to make it a little bit more clear

```
data = {"invoice_id": ["149877RV", "149877RV", "149877RV", "149877RV", "149877RV", "149877RV", "149877RV", "150210", "150210", "150210", "150210"],
        "approver": ["Jane Doe", "Joe Manchin", "Michael Frank", "Kevin Holder", "Michael Frank", "Michael Frank", "Jane Doe", "Jim Halpert", "Mike Smith", "FP&A", "Michael Scott"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

approver_1, approver_2 = "Michael Frank", "Kevin Holder"

results = []
for id in set(df["invoice_id"]):
    approvers_per_id = set(df.loc[df.loc[:, "invoice_id"] == id, "approver"])
    if approver_1 in approvers_per_id and approver_2 in approvers_per_id:
        results.append(df.loc[df.loc[:, "invoice_id"] == id])
print(results)
```

This returns

```
[  invoice_id       approver
0   149877RV       Jane Doe
1   149877RV    Joe Manchin
2   149877RV  Michael Frank
3   149877RV   Kevin Holder
4   149877RV  Michael Frank
5   149877RV  Michael Frank
6   149877RV       Jane Doe]
```